# MotionLayout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-motionlayout, android-jetpack-compose

> This might be a little soon, but there should be a workaround for this

**TL;DR**

Is there any way to use **Composable** components of Jetpack Compose in **MotionLayout**?
Is such combination in the road map of MotionLayout or Compose?

---

Is there an alternative for it in Jetpack compose that can do the same?

Since any view that wants to be modified in the motion scene, compose functions can not be modified in a motion scene.

**Problem**

I want to animate an Image in the center of a `Surface` and scale it up and down in a specific duration.

[image]

Using motion, you can define keyframes in each step.

*The Ui is made using Composable function*. **How can I do what I could with MotionLayout in Compose?**

---

**Jetpack compose**: v1.0.0-alpha02

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `transitionDefinition`, check below example and adopt it based on your needs.

```
enum class State {
    A, B
}

private val scale = FloatPropKey()
private val definition = transitionDefinition {
    state(State.A) {
        this[scale] = 1f
    }
    state(State.B) {
        this[scale] = 5f
    }
    transition(fromState = State.A, toState = State.B) {
        scale using tween(
            durationMillis = 3000,
            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun AnimateComponentScale() {
    var initialState by remember { mutableStateOf(State.A) }
    var toState by remember { mutableStateOf(State.B) }

    val state = transition(
        definition = definition,
        initState = initialState,
        toState = toState
    ) { state ->
        when (state) {
            State.A -> {
                initialState = State.A
                toState = State.B
            }
            State.B -> {
                initialState = State.B
                toState = State.A
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        gravity = ContentGravity.Center,
        backgroundColor = Color.Cyan
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(50.dp)) {
            scale(scaleX = state[scale], scaleY = state[scale]) {
                drawRect(color = Color(255, 138, 128))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TransitionDefinition has been deprecated in Compose Animation [Version 1.0.0-alpha11](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation#1.0.0-alpha11). What do you use nowadays?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation

Answer (score 2):

You can now use a subset of `MotionLayout` features direction within Compose using the latest release of constraintlayout-compose (`1.0.0-beta02` at the time of writing).

The instructions from the documentaion show you can add it to your project with:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-beta02")
}
```

The documentation also provides a simple example of transitioning between two constraint sets:

```kotlin
@Preview(group = "motion8")
@Composable
public fun AttributesRotationXY() {
    var animateToEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val progress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (animateToEnd) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(6000)
    )
    Column {
        MotionLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(400.dp)
                .background(Color.White),
            motionScene = MotionScene("""{
                ConstraintSets: {   // all ConstraintSets
                  start: {          // constraint set id = "start"
                    a: {            // Constraint for widget id='a'
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      start: ['parent', 'start', 16],
                      bottom: ['parent', 'bottom', 16]
                    }
                  },
                  end: {         // constraint set id = "start"
                    a: {
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      //rotationZ: 390,
                      end: ['parent', 'end', 16],
                      top: ['parent', 'top', 16]
                    }
                  }
                },
                Transitions: {            // All Transitions in here 
                  default: {              // transition named 'default'
                    from: 'start',        // go from Transition "start"
                    to: 'end',            // go to Transition "end"
                    pathMotionArc: 'startHorizontal',  // move in arc 
                    KeyFrames: {          // All keyframes go here
                      KeyAttributes: [    // keyAttributes key frames go here
                        {
                          target: ['a'],              // This keyAttributes group target id "a"
                          frames: [25,50,75],         // 3 points on progress 25% , 50% and 75%
                          rotationX: [0, 45, 60],     // the rotationX angles are a spline from 0,0,45,60,0
                          rotationY: [60, 45, 0],     // the rotationX angles are a spline from 0,60,45,0,0
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
            }"""),
            debug = EnumSet.of(MotionLayoutDebugFlags.SHOW_ALL),
            progress = progress) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("a")
                .background(Color.Red))
        }

        Button(onClick = { animateToEnd = !animateToEnd }) {
            Text(text = "Run")
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more and follow the progress in [this wiki](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Introduction-to-MotionLayout-in-Compose) and [the constraint layout repository](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout).